# Count number of rows in database between two time stamps

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my database I'm using the current time stamp based on the customer orders, stored in a table. I want to know, within two time periods, how many customers order a request. Suppose `10:12:16` to `13:32:54`, in this time period how many(count) customers requested? In the same way as in between 2 dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE time_stamp_column BETWEEN '10:12:16' AND '13:32:54';
```

Answer (score 0):

The Simple My SQL Query is this :

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE time_stamp_column BETWEEN '10:12:16' AND '13:32:54';
```

Using Codeigniter's Query Builder you can do this :

```
public function getCount(){
   return $this->db->get_where('your_table','time_stamp_column BETWEEN "10:12:16" AND "13:32:54"')->num_rows();
}
```